# Incompatible changes in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a javascript program that selects a rectangle in a google map, based upon the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/JsAJA/3/

```
function initMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43, -89);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    }
    var mapElem = $("#map-canvas");
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem[0], settings);
    rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                map: map
            });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(mEvent) {
        map.draggable = false;
        latlng1 = mEvent.latLng;
        dragging = true;
        pos1 = mEvent.pixel;
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(mEvent) {
        latlng2 = mEvent.latLng;
        showRect();
    });
/*
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function(mEvent) {
        map.draggable = true;
        dragging = false;
    });
    */
    google.maps.event.addListener(rect, 'mouseup', function(data){
        map.draggable = true;
        dragging = false;

        var lat1 = latlng1.lat();
        var lat2 = latlng2.lat();
        var minLat = lat1<lat2?lat1:lat2;
        var maxLat = lat1<lat2?lat2:lat1;
        var lng1 = latlng1.lng();
        var lng2 = latlng2.lng();
        var minLng = lng1<lng2?lng1:lng2;
        var maxLng = lng1<lng2?lng2:lng1;
        alert('Datbase query for the following bounds:\n\nlat: ' + minLat + ' to ' + maxLat+ '\n\nlng: ' + minLng + ' to ' + maxLng);
    });


}

function showRect() {
    if(dragging){
        if (rect === undefined) {
            rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                map: map
            });
        }
        var latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(latlng1, latlng2);
        rect.setBounds(latLngBounds);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, since today, the code does not work anymore. Why does it not work anymore?

Comment: "the code does not work anymore" is not a very good description of the symptoms.

Comment: @Marcelo: "I've created a javascript program that selects a rectangle in a google map" [...] the code does not work any more: So it will not select the rectangle anymore...

Comment: If you haven't changed anything, does it still work with the ["frozen" version of the API (currently v=3.9)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks! Yes, that worked! So I now know it's related to the new api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ["frozen" version of the API (currently v=3.9)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)

If that works, create an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) in the issue tracker referencing this question and your jsfiddle.